# How to know when "karma" test cases are run and reports are generated?

Tags: automated-testing, javascript, mocha

I have written unit test cases using **Karma + Mocha + Chai** and generated reports using karma-html-reporter. When the report got generated, I want to send the report to my team through mail. I need to know when the test cases are run and the reports are generated. How could I know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have listened to the event "run_complete" and I have done my actions.